# How to set Windows Terminal to open bash at a specific folder?

Tags: git-bash, windows-terminal

How can I configure a Windows Terminal profile to open Git Bash, but setting it to navigate to a specific path?

I've tried to set `--cd=\"D:/path/""` but it does not work:

```
%PROGRAMFILES%/git/usr/bin/bash.exe -i -l --cd=\"D:/path/""
/usr/bin/bash: --: invalid option
```

Comment: Do you want a shortcut to do this?  Opening in bash or cmd?

Comment: No, it's a Windows Terminal profile. It uses the command line param to open the bash.

Comment: Are you talking about Windows Terminal as in  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/terminal/  ?  Bash doesn't have a --cd option.

Comment: Yes, that Windows Terminal app. It's possible to add `Git Bash` as a profile.